# Using Java to organize array input into a table?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that receives an array. I want to have it organize the results into ranges (like 60-69). It also needs to know how many of the numbers it received fit into which ranges so it can put them in accordingly. The way I've seen to create tabs in a table is

```
System.out.print("Column1/tColumn2");
```

How do you go about organizing the array data into a range? Do you specify it with a bunch of IF statements? And I assume you use a counter to tally up how many numbers fit into which ranges?

EDIT: Here's the code at present.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;

public class Salary {
int salary;
int sales;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
   int Salary;
   Salary salary = new Salary();

   System.out.print( "Please enter the amount each employee brought in:");  
   String sales = input.nextLine();
   String salesArray[] = sales.split(" ");


   for(int i=0; i<salesArray.length; i++){
   Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(salesArray[i]);

   System.out.print(salesArray[i] + " ");
   if (Integer.parseInt(salesArray[i]) <= 0) {
   System.out.println("Please enter a value greater than zero");}
   else {
   Salary = ((myInt/100) * 9) + 200;
   System.out.print(Salary); }
   }

   int two = 0;  //declared a variable, starting it at 0 and intending to increment it
                 //with input from the array

   System.out.print("Range/t#ofEmployees");
   for(int i=0; i<salesArray.length; i++) {
   if (salesArray[i] <= 200){}  //Error on the if statement, using the wrong operand
   else{ two++;}      //Attempt at the table and increment. 

   }

}

}
```

Comment: if you can't find an approach, take some random dummy data, and solve this problem by hand on a piece of paper with that dummy data ... while you do that write down what you do ... then try to formalize those steps

Comment: "I want to have it organize the results into ranges (like 60-69)" could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: i think the task is to aggregate scalar values into groups counters ... 5 events where the value is between 60 and 69 ... 16 events where the value is between 70 and 79 ... etc

Comment: Its so much easier using a hash table!! :D, but it depends if he learned that yet

Answer (score 2):

i won't post an implementation, since this is homework, but think of this:

your array can be sorted ...

you can itterate that array, and count something up if the current value is less than a certain boundary ... once it is greater you can print one range and startover for the next range ...

boundaries can change from range to range ...

Comment: Also note that Java has built-in sorting methods (for collections or arrays)